# i would like to know why my getName function isn't working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

using namespace std;

void myFunction(optional<string> name = nullopt) {
  if (name == nullopt) {
    cout << "I wish I knew your name!" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "Hello " << name.value() << "!" << endl;
  }
}

void getName(string Name){
    cout << "input name: " << endl;
    cin >> Name;
}
int main()
{
      myFunction();
      getName();
      myFunction(Name);

  return 0;
}
```

what would i do to make the getName function working ive tried a few things like adding a string as such `string Name = getName()` but it wasnt working either.

Comment: Can you describe what "isn't working" means? Compiler error? Runtime error? Unexpected behavior? What happened? What did you expect?

Comment: Your posted code isn't consistent. Post an actual version of the code you are using. Not half of one version and half of a different version.

Comment: Name isn’t a field in the scope of main.

Comment: Are you familiar with what `return` means in C++? Do you see how it would be relevant to the problem? (Hint: when you call `getName`, you want to get some information *out of* the function, right? How does that normally work?)

Comment: `void getName(string Name){`  should not take a `Name` passed by value. That means the calling code would pass a Name to getName() and not retrieve it from getName().

Comment: expected primary expression before Name

Comment: The error is correct. There is no `Name` variable in the scope of `int main()`

Comment: This one's going to be one of those questions whose challenge will be to decide which one of the eagerly-posted answers turns out to be the one that misses the most of the forest, for the trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a function with a return value instead..

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void myFunction(optional<string> name = nullopt) {
  if (name == nullopt) {
    cout << "I wish I knew your name!" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "Hello " << name.value() << "!" << endl;
  }
}

string getName(){
    string Name;
    cout << "input name: " << endl;
    cin >> Name;
    return Name;
}
int main()
{
      
      myFunction();
      myFunction(getName());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this worked for me ! wowwwww thanks so much. i can't  believe it was so simple. i was trying too hard "string Name = getName(Name) " i should have just tried this first. now i know .

Comment: No problem, just mark it as a solution if it helped.

Comment: *this worked for me !* -- How could it have worked, when `Name` is passed by value in `getName`?  As soon as `getName` returns, that `Name` goes up in a puff of smoke.

Comment: @drescherjm Re-Edit, and I have tested it out on my system. It works, you are right, no global variables.

Comment: for some reason the else function doesn't grab the name. the program runs but no name is shown.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, that was an Issue. I believe I have fixed it now. It works on my system.

Comment: @HectorAgosto Check the latest edit. I had some.. major issues with the previos versions... But now I have tested this version, and it works. It shows the name.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, Your code can not be compiled, because there's no definition of `Name` in function `main()`. Even if you fix it, it won't work properly. Because the `Name` in function `main()` and `getName()` are not the same one. The `Name` in function `getName()` is just a copy of `Name` in function `main()`.
To fix it, try change the type of `Name` in `getName()` to `string&`.

```cpp
void getName(string& name) {

  cout << "input name: " << endl;
  cin >> name;
}

int main() {
  
  string name;
  getName(name);
}
```